# Importing HTML to Typescript to use as TemplateStringLiteral

Tags: html, typescript

This is my first time using typescript, and want to incorporate typescript into my webpack build.

I'm using ts-loader and babel-loader to load the ts files and right now trying to load html file into the script. (Polymer Lit HTML)

```
import template from './template.html';

render(props) {
    return html([`${template}`]);
}
```

And here's the error that I got

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TemplateStringsArray'.
Property 'raw' is missing in type 'string[]'.
```

Any idea how to solve this? Seems like I need to convert the template into TemplateStringsArray but I basically didn't know what to do.

**Update 1:**

I create html.d.ts file with content like this.

```
declare module '*.html' {
    const content: string;
    export default content;
}
```

But it seems like template have a value of undefined.

html is a function from lit-html

```
export declare const html: (strings: TemplateStringsArray, ...values: any[]) => TemplateResult;
```

**Update 2**

After some tinkering with the answer provided below found out that the returned values is not quite right. The returned value right now is `{raw: values}` however I need to change it to `[raw: values]`.

```
interface TemplateStringsArray extends ReadonlyArray<string> {
    readonly raw: ReadonlyArray<string>;
}
```

This is the part of html function from lit-html

```
export const html = (strings, ...values) => {
    return new TemplateResult(strings, values, 'html', extendedPartCallback)
};
```

Basically I need that part of strings is changed to `[raw : val]` not `{raw: val}`

Comment: What is the `html` function? Where is that being imported from?

Comment: I bet this is lit html, so I would propose to try `this.html\`${template}\``

Comment: It is lit html, 

`export declare const html: (strings: TemplateStringsArray, ...values: any[]) => TemplateResult;`

Comment: Like this?

`_render(props) {return this.html`${template}`}`

Comment: I'm trying to add html`${template}` but it wont rendered anything, lookslike template have a value of undefined.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Importing raw HTML and passing it to lit-html probably isn't going to do much of anything useful. Any expressions in the template won't actually work.

Comment: More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Raw_strings But it will not work as @JustinFagnani mentioned

Answer (score 6):

Regarding to your error:

> TS2345: Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TemplateStringsArray'.
>   Property 'raw' is missing in type 'string[]'.

You have to wrap the parameter to fit the TemplateStringsArray interface like this:

```
const stringArray = [`${template}`];
return html({raw: stringArray, ...stringArray} as TemplateStringsArray);
```

This way you provide the needed `raw` property and tell the `html()`-function that the given object is of type `TemplateStringsArray`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, it point to the right direction however I'm afraid my limited knowledge of this issue need your expertise as well.

You see, the returned value for the code that you specify above is `{raw : values}` however the library that I'm using need the value returned as `[raw: values]` thats why the render function that I use return undefined. What part that I need to change in order to fix this?

Ill also include some information about the TemplateStringsArray itself in my question above.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I am wondering, that the lib you are using is exprecting an Array like you described, because this does strictly spoken not match the interface. but anyway, I am glad that you fixed it.

Comment: Following this method, I get an error from the shady-render.js. It's expecting a 'join' method on the TemplateStringArray object that doesn't seem to get defined for some reason.

Answer (score 6):

The final version of the answer that working properly is like this :

```
const stringArray = [`${template}`] as any;
stringArray.raw = [`${template}`];
return html(stringArray as TemplateStringsArray);
```